# submitting form in ajax in codeigniter, i am not getting value in success message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using PHP codeigniter in my project, I am submitting form using ajax call i am not getting value in success message, I have attached you my code

Ajax call:

```
function addlocation(){

    var state = $('#state').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var pincode = $('#pincode').val();

    var dataString = 'state='+ state + '&city='+ city + '&pincode='+ pincode;
    //alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"<?=base_url();?>masterentry/addLocation/",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (mresp) {
            alert(mresp);
            // $('#successMsg').css('display','block');
            // $('#successMsg').fadeOut(3000);
            //alert($("#alertInvite").attr("style"));
            //console.log(mresp);
        }

    });

}
```

Controller:

```
//add location
public function addLocation(){
    // $result = $this->masterentry_model->addEnable();
    // //echo "hello world";
    // if($result == 1){
    //  echo "Location added successfully";
    // }

    $result = $this->masterentry_model->addEnable();

    if($result>0){

        echo "location added success";
        //$this->load->view("full_profile",$data);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public function addEnable(){
    $state = $this->input->post('state');
    $city = $this->input->post('city');
    $pincode = $this->input->post('pincode');
    $createdOn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if($state != ''){
        echo "INSERT INTO `enable_location`(state, city, pincode, site_enable, status, created_on) VALUES('$state', '$city', '$pincode', '$createdOn', 'enable', '$createdOn')";
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `enable_location`(state, city, pincode, site_enable, status, created_on) VALUES('$state', '$city', '$pincode', '$createdOn', 'enable', '$createdOn')");
        $affect = $this->db->affected_rows();
    }


    return 1;       
}
```

in above code, I am not getting "location added success" in ajax success page. I dont know where i am mistaking.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Turn on error reporting?!

Comment: What is mresp  use data instead of it

Comment: remove echo your insert query from your model file

Comment: use your browser console to see the error. or use postman to see the response from the url.

Comment: Is your database autoloaded ? If not, you should add `$this->load->database();` in your controller

Comment: Try changing "base_url()" to "site_url()" The base_url method returns the path to your front directory. However, CI runs though index.php

Comment: Thanks for your replies. the value get inserted in database, but return 1 is not returning. Thats what i am not getting value in mresp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

View:

```
function addlocation(){

    var state = $('#state').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var pincode = $('#pincode').val();

    //alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"<?=base_url('masterentry/addLocation');?>",
        data: {state: state, city: city, pincode: pincode},
        cache: false,
        success: function (mresp) {
            alert(mresp);
            // $('#successMsg').css('display','block');
            // $('#successMsg').fadeOut(3000);
            //alert($("#alertInvite").attr("style"));
            //console.log(mresp);
        }

    });

}
```

Controller:

```
public function addLocation()
{
    if ($this->masterentry_model->addEnable($this->input->post('state'), $this->input->post('city'), $this->input->post('pincode'))) {
        echo 'Location added successfully.';
    } else {
        echo 'Not added.';
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function addEnable($state = false, $city = false, $pincode = false){
    $createdOn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($state){//maybe you need to know rest of passing variables too or set default to something else 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `enable_location`(state, city, pincode, site_enable, status, created_on) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, 'enable', ?)";
        $this->db->query($sql, array($state, $city, $pincode, $createdOn, 'enable', $createdOn ));
        if ( (int)$this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply friends. actually i was wrong given submitted in onclick function insted of this "<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" style="width:100px;" onclick="addlocation();">ADD</button>" I have return "<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" style="width:100px;" onclick="addlocation();">ADD</button>" in form section

Comment: You can remove `addLocation` from button and make code executes from anonimous function like `$('submit').on('click', function{/*rest of JS code*/});`